# How to solve system of equations?

Tags: problem-solving

I want to sove the system of equations $$\begin{cases}
x^3 y-y^4=7,\\
x^2 y+2 xy^2+y^3=9.
\end{cases}
$$
I tried divide these two equations we obtain
$$\dfrac{x^3 - y^3}{(x+y)^2 } = \dfrac{7}{9}$$
From here, I don't know how to solve.

Comment: Here's one try: $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We'll prove that $(2,1)$ is the only real solution.  First note that if $y = 0$, the second equation is unsolvable, so $y\neq 0$.

Solving the second equation for $x$ via the quadratic formula gives \begin{align*} x &= \frac{-2y^2 \pm \sqrt{4y^4-4y(y^3-9)}}{2y}\\ &= \frac{-y^2\pm 3\sqrt{y}}{y} \\ &= -y \pm y^{-\frac{1}{2}}.\end{align*}

In particular, $y \geq 0$.  Subbing this into the first equation gives \begin{align*}7 &= \left(-y \pm 3y^{-\frac{1}{2}} \right)^3 y - y^4 \\ &=  -2y^4\pm 9y^{\frac{5}{2}}-27y\pm 27y^{-\frac{1}{2}}.\end{align*}

This is equivalent to $$ 0 = -2y^{\frac{9}{2}} \pm 9y^{\frac{6}{2}}-27y^{\frac{3}{2}} -7y^\frac{1}{2} \pm 27.$$

Now, substitute in $z = \sqrt{y}$, which is possible since we already know $y\geq 0$.  This gives $$0 = -2z^9 \pm 9z^6 - 27z^3 -7z \pm 27$$

If we choose the $-$ sign, then clearly there is no solution with $z$ real, so we must have $$0 = -2z^9 + 9z^6 - 27z^3-7z+27.$$

Now, using the rational roots theorem, maple, direct inspection, etc, we see $z=1$ is a solution.

I claim that $f(z)-2z^9 + 9z^6 - 27z^3 - 7z + 27$ is always decreasing, so $z=1$ is the only solution.

To see this, compute the derivative, getting $f'(z)=-18z^8 + 54z^5-81z^2 - 7 = 9(-2z^8 + 6z^5-9z^2 - \frac{7}{9})$.  I claim this is always negative.  The $9$ out in front doesn't effect this, so we'll ignore it in intermediate computations.

Why is $f'(z)$ always negative?  Lets find its maximum.  So, take another derivative, getting $f''(z)-16z^7+30z^4-18z = 2z(-8z^6 + 15z^3 - 9)$.  Of course, this is $0$ when $z=0$, but the other part is quadratic in $z^3$ and so we see that it's never $0$.  Since $f'(z)$ goes to $-\infty$ as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$, it follows that if it only has one critical point, this must be a max.  So, the max of $f'(z)$ occurs when $z = 0$, where $f'(0) = -7 < 0$.

Since $f'(z) < 0$, $f(z)$ is always decreasing, so $z= 1$ must be its only solution.

When $z=1$, $\sqrt{y} = 1$ so $y=1$, and subbing back in shows that $x=2$.

Comment: Please check your solution at "Solving the second equation for x via the quadratic formula gives..."

Comment: @I'm not sure what you're referring to, it still looks ok to me.

Comment: Note that, $$\sqrt{4y^4 -4y(y^3 -9)}=6\sqrt{y}$$.

Comment: You're right!!  Let me see how this messes with everything...

Comment: It took forever, but it's fixed (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Guess and check works: $x=2$, $y=1$. (I tried forcing $x+y$ to be 3 and that's what I got.)

For a more general method for finding all solutions, I suppose applying the appropriate root-finding algorithm to approximate the solutions could work.

Comment: Well, that's *one* solution. Maybe there are others?

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x^3y-y^4%3D7%2C+y%28x%2By%29^2%3D9) finds only that real root.

Comment: Huh. Guess I got pretty lucky then.

Comment: Depends on where the problem comes from.  Class problems often have solutions you can find that way.  The rational root theorem is a great example-it works better in class than in real life.  This looks like one that was supposed to be solved the way you did.  Looking for small integer solutions is often productive.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases}
x^3 y-y^4=7,\\
x^2 y+2 xy^2+y^3=9.
\end{cases}$$

$x^3y-y^4=y(x^3-y^3)$, while $x^2y+2xy^2+y^3=y(x+y)^3$.

We try the transformation $x+y=z$.

Then $y(x^3-y^3)=y(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=y(z-2y)(z^2-xy)=y(z-2y)(z^2-(z-y)y)=$
$-2y^4+3y^3z-3y^2z^2+yz^3=7$
On the other hand, the second equation gives $yz^2=9$, so $y=\frac{9}{z^2}$. We expand and then notice that it is actually equal to $9(z^3-18)(z^6-9z^3+81)=7z^8$. Then we get $z=3$ as a root.

The problem is that I do not know how do I show that there are no other roots, but probably someone who knows calculus can be able to resolve this? or probably by a weird factoring?